# How to order matrices in a list in a descending?

Tags: r, list, matrix

Assume we have these 2 lists: List one

```
c1 <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)
c2 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c3 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c4 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c5 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c6 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c7 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c8 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c9 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c10 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c11 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c12<- c1+(rnorm(10))
c13<- c1+(rnorm(10))
c14 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c15 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c16 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c17 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
c18 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
clist <- list(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18)

[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0700367 -0.5578757
[2,]  0.4093932  1.0749494
[3,]  1.1078936 -1.0020313
[4,] -0.7811367 -0.9588735
[5,] -0.7702231 -0.4892086

[[2]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.57797328  0.2617391
[2,] -0.87241974  1.1265720
[3,]  1.84947367 -0.7139085
[4,] -1.63986024 -0.9102586
[5,]  0.06221699 -0.6733914

[[3]]
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  2.289326 -0.77862436
[2,] -1.022810  1.11059490
[3,]  1.036657  0.06886355
[4,] -1.383734 -0.99963748
[5,] -2.141255 -1.29084565

[[4]]
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  0.5070891 -0.45562637
[2,]  1.0324446  1.41556011
[3,]  2.4718491 -1.39879189
[4,] -0.6604285 -0.47753910
[5,]  0.7938556 -0.07936295

[[5]]
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 3.3870090  0.5420060
[2,] 0.5712447  1.3975933
[3,] 1.3072899 -0.6763534
[4,] 0.5605419 -0.4463263
[5,] 0.7240062 -0.3466927

[[6]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  2.31201726 -1.0508046
[2,] -0.06529705  2.3007519
[3,]  1.01335486  0.2294716
[4,]  0.30277459 -0.9007592
[5,] -1.01667980 -0.2653819

[[7]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.72524700 -1.1381316
[2,] -0.70805611  1.4912682
[3,]  0.02581648 -0.1799978
[4,] -0.69420585 -2.0897702
[5,]  0.28893614 -1.3320487

[[8]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0035684 -1.7132670
[2,]  0.4127813  1.5093681
[3,]  1.3565442 -1.3588956
[4,] -2.8350358 -1.0903141
[5,] -2.4558814 -0.9655129

[[9]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.08047188 -0.8820000
[2,] -0.19398400 -0.2308767
[3,]  0.09548916 -1.3369467
[4,] -0.68126015 -1.9699754
[5,]  0.49449792  0.4916281

[[10]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.2658601 -2.2107617
[2,] -0.1627423  1.4692983
[3,]  3.4493613 -1.3103298
[4,] -0.3894654 -1.4713198
[5,]  0.8240821 -0.2250143

[[11]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  2.9858303  0.3477594
[2,] -1.5882846  0.5219365
[3,]  1.5934080 -1.7183402
[4,] -0.9507265 -0.9574800
[5,] -0.9013779 -0.8767775

[[12]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.7939398 -2.018252
[2,]  0.6124091  2.571972
[3,]  1.9311252 -1.533483
[4,] -0.1643360 -2.611893
[5,] -0.6491992 -1.580492

[[13]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.1829224 -1.0877178
[2,]  1.6820163  1.3020885
[3,]  0.3300722 -0.5611728
[4,] -1.7108015 -1.5658648
[5,] -0.5647340 -0.4141432

[[14]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  2.19552384 -1.0960342
[2,]  1.15353759  0.5215864
[3,] -0.48139839  0.1075568
[4,] -0.93807917 -2.6135192
[5,]  0.01308484 -0.4473025

[[15]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.3210720  0.5649543
[2,]  2.0667212  1.0788922
[3,]  1.4608440 -0.4755102
[4,] -1.7570569 -2.4803738
[5,] -0.6317204 -0.3547752

[[16]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.8485633 -0.3334503
[2,]  0.6451695  0.7377303
[3,] -0.4772256 -0.2918937
[4,] -0.7817388 -1.2121758
[5,] -0.2658948 -1.2121535

[[17]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.1988099 -3.2396990
[2,]  1.9654758 -0.3612864
[3,]  1.1614214 -0.8344391
[4,] -0.5958542 -1.7135859
[5,] -1.0568211 -0.7607357

[[18]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  2.0347305 -1.5804555
[2,] -0.6078962  0.7648275
[3,]  1.2695973 -0.4216392
[4,] -1.8700421  0.6019247
[5,] -1.1738761 -1.3271278
```

List 2:

```
a1 <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)
a2 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
a3 <- c1+(rnorm(10))
alist <- list(a1,a2,a3)

[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0700367 -0.5578757
[2,]  0.4093932  1.0749494
[3,]  1.1078936 -1.0020313
[4,] -0.7811367 -0.9588735
[5,] -0.7702231 -0.4892086

[[2]]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.57797328  0.2617391
[2,] -0.87241974  1.1265720
[3,]  1.84947367 -0.7139085
[4,] -1.63986024 -0.9102586
[5,]  0.06221699 -0.6733914

[[3]]
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  2.289326 -0.77862436
[2,] -1.022810  1.11059490
[3,]  1.036657  0.06886355
[4,] -1.383734 -0.99963748
[5,] -2.141255 -1.29084565
```

I want to insert a matrix from the second list after every 6 matrices in the first list, so I would have a pattern of `c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 a1 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 a2 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 a3`

I have the following code:

`names(clist) <- paste0("c", seq_along(clist))
names(alist) <- paste0("c", seq_along(alist)*6, "a")
x <- c(clist, alist)
x <- x[order(names(x))]`

So before running `x <- x[order(names(x))]`, `names(x)` looks like this:

`[1] "c1"   "c2"   "c3"   "c4"   "c5"   "c6"   "c7"   "c8"   "c9"   "c10"  "c11" 
[12] "c12"  "c13"  "c14"  "c15"  "c16"  "c17"  "c18"  "c6a"  "c12a" "c18a"`

However, after running `x <- x[order(names(x))]` the order of matrices in the list becomes:

`[1] "c1"   "c10"  "c11"  "c12"  "c12a" "c13"  "c14"  "c15"  "c16"  "c17"  "c18" 
[12] "c18a" "c2"   "c3"   "c4"   "c5"   "c6"   "c6a"  "c7"   "c8"   "c9"`

I need it to be

`[1] "c1"   "c2"   "c3"   "c4"   "c5"   "c6" "c6a"  "c7"   "c8"   "c9"   "c10"  "c11" 
[12] "c12" "c12a" "c13"  "c14"  "c15"  "c16"  "c17"  "c18"  "c18a"`

If the number of matrices was smaller than 10, then the code would work perfectly. However, R doesn't think that `c10` is larger than `c2`.

I thought that a solution to this problem would be to run `sortedc <- mixedsort(sort(names(x)))` from the package `gtools`, which sorts `names(x)` in the desired order, and then run `x <- x[order(sortedc)]`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Two side notes. First, your data construction is polluting your environment with dozens of useless objects. To construct clist with a single additional object, do the following: `cMat <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2); clist <- replicate(18, cMat + rnorm(10), simplify=FALSE)`. Second, use `set.seed` to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: That's incredibly useful, thank you.

Comment: If `sortedc` is in the desired order you could have gotten your desired results with just `x <- x[sortedc]`. In fact I'll post as an answer since it's so much simpler than the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say `sortedc` is in the desired order, you could have gotten your desired results with just:

```
 x <- x[sortedc]
```

The `"["` function will accept a vector of names as an argument and do either selection or reordering of its elements. Note: I thought that you would have only needed:

```
 sortedc <- mixedsort( names(x))
```

Here's the code test:

```
> library(gtools)
> cMat <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2); clist <- replicate(21, cMat + rnorm(10), simplify=FALSE)
> names(clist) <- c( paste0("c", 1:18), paste0("c", seq(6,18,by=6), "a") )
> x <- clist[ mixedsort(names(clist) ) ]
> names(x)
 [1] "c1"   "c2"   "c3"   "c4"   "c5"   "c6"   "c6a"  "c7"   "c8"   "c9"   "c10"  "c11"  "c12"  "c12a"
[15] "c13"  "c14"  "c15"  "c16"  "c17"  "c18"  "c18a"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is so simple that I feel embarrassed for asking this question. I am still an absolute beginner, so I tend to miss some very elementary details.

Comment: This is a good example of the power of R's indexing facilities. I think it was natural to think (incorrectly) that the `order` function might be needed where you put it, but the character indexing with the the "["-functipn  provided it automagically. If you had a vector that was unsorted, then a pre-`sort` or inside-`sort` would be needed for "[" to work on. You should play around with the results of `sort` and `order` to see how they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using the `purrr`package:

```
library(purrr)
clist_split <-
  split(clist, gl(length(clist) / 6, 6))  # split the list into chunks of 6
alist <- map(alist, list)  # make elements of alist lists themselves
temp <- map2(clist_split, alist, append)  # append one element of alist to each 6 lists in each element of clist_split
result <- unlist(temp, recursive = FALSE)  # flatten list by one level
```

But please note that to me it seems like that you have a typo in `alist <- list(c1,c2,c3)`.  Shouldn't it be `alist <- list(a1,a2,a3)`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `for` loop. Here is a base R method that uses a `for` loop and the `append` function.

```
# construct data
set.seed(1234)
cMat <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)
clist <- replicate(18, cMat + rnorm(10), simplify=FALSE)
# values to insert into list
myVals <- list("snack", "time", "now")
```

Given this data, construct an index for insertion and then run the loop.

```
# construct index for placement
idx <- seq(7, 21, 7)
# run loop
for(i in seq_along(idx)) clist <- append(clist, myVals[[i]], idx[i]-1L)
```

Let's check the first inserted value

```
clist[[7]]
[1] "snack"
```